# IE numerator waitforseconds C# in Unity not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity and would like to pause the script for a few seconds before playing a sound. But, for some unknown reason, it doesn't work! I have been through countless  forums to see what I've been doing wrong. But according to Unity's docummentation, I'm doing it right? Can someone please help me on how to fix this? If it helps: this script is for a trigger. Code below

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class mechstarttrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rl;
    public GameObject mech;

    void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        rl.SetActive(false);
        mech.SetActive(false);
    }

    IEnumerator waitsec()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider colision)
    {
        rl.SetActive(true);
        mech.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(waitsec());
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManger>().Play("1");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a Coroutine does **NOT** delay the code that used `StartCoroutine`!

What you rather want/need to do either

```
IEnumerator waitsec()
{
    rl.SetActive(true);
    mech.SetActive(true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    FindObjectOfType<AudioManger>().Play("1");
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider colision)
{
    StartCoroutine(waitsec());
}
```

Or you can go fancy and use a callback structure

```
IEnumerator waitsec(Action whenDone)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider colision)
{
    rl.SetActive(true);
    mech.SetActive(true);

    StartCoroutine(waitsec(()=>
    {
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManger>().Play("1");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }));
}
```

or actually the easiest way for you: `OnTriggerEnter` can be a Coroutine itself

```
IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (Collider colision)
{
    rl.SetActive(true);
    mech.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    FindObjectOfType<AudioManger>().Play("1");
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

---

Also side note: What exactly is

```
Time.timeScale = 0;
Time.timeScale = 1;
```

supposed to do? ^^ Just keep the last line

Comment: OH MY GOD! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I can't believe it was as simple as that thank you thank you thank you